# Chart.js Charts not loading until hard refresh [Laravel] [Laravel Charts]

Tags: javascript, laravel, chart.js

I seem to be having difficulties in getting my charts to display without a hard refresh (ctrl+shift+r).

I'm using the [ConsoleTVs/Charts](https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts) Laravel package with the Chart.js chart set.

I have included the `<script src="{{ asset('js/Chart.min.js') }}"></script>` in my `<head>` and below that I have the scripts loading for the charts `{!! $chartA->scripts() !!}` and `{!! $chartB->scripts() !!}`

The charts show sporadically though; most of the time they need a hard refresh to show.

I have added `version()` to my webpack file for the `chart.min.js` script to prevent it from being cached `mix.js('resources/js/Chart.min.js', 'public/js').version();`

Any advice?

Here's an example of what's happening:- [Demo](https://gifyu.com/image/wfay)

Comment: Have you tried `.update( )` after the page fully loaded?

Comment: @Tygo Is this on the `mix.js('resources/js/Chart.min.js', 'public/js').version()` line? `.update()` doesn't seem to be a function

Comment: You have to put the chart object inside a variable. Then you can trigger the `.update()` on that variable.
You should try this because it seems like your chart is trying to load to fast.

Comment: Found the issue - the `app.js` file loads jquery from the `bootstrap.js` file. When removing the line `window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');` my charts load fine, except then everything else that require jquery in my application stops working

Comment: Any ideas??????

Answer (score 0):

Use scripts from CDNJS:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js" charset="utf-8">
 </script>
```

use :

```
{!! $yourVar->script() !!}
```

at the end of your template Ref: [here](https://dev.to/arielmejiadev/use-laravel-charts-in-laravel-5bbm)